# Docker compose auto start al reiniciar

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Necesito lanzar un docker-compose en un ubuntu-server cada vez que este se reinicie.

He probado a crear un crontab así:

```
@reboot docker-compose -f /home/user/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Pero cuando lo reinicio esto no ha dado resultados, alguna idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo único que necesitas para que se reinicie solo, es `restart: always` en el **yml**.

Por lo que si tu `docker-compose.yml` es este:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Alcanza con que le pongas `restart: always` en el *container*:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Luego, en la carpeta, haces `docker-compose up -d` (para que arranque como un proceso aparte) y listo, cada vez que se reinicie *Ubuntu*, arranca el *container*.

Answer (score 1):

Un buen consejo es ponerlo como:

```
restart:on-failure:5
```

así limito a 5 veces los intentos de subir el contenedor ante fallas.
Si lo dejas en `always` intentará eternamente subir el contenedor y eso te puede significar un consumo de recursos que degrade tu sistema.